# Neo4j - Unknown 'toFloat' function in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to run a cypher query where I have to compare a value stored as a String, but when I use the function `toFloat`, I get an error :

```
Unknown function 'toFloat' (line 2, column 7)
"WHERE toFloat(r.acquiredValue) >= 100000"
       ^
```

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.1, and according to the [Neo4j Cypher Refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/), the function exists, and even by looking at the source code of the community edition, I can find that the function is written.

Have you ever got this error ? How can I convert a string to float in a cypher query ? Thanks.

**EDIT :** Here is the query trying to run

```
MATCH (profile)<-[:HAS_PROFILE]-(c:Customer)-[r:HAS_PRODUCT]->(product)
WHERE toFloat(r.acquiredValue) >= 100000
RETURN c.customerId AS CustomerID, profile.code AS ProfileCode, product.name AS ProductName, r.acquiredValue AS AcquiredValue
ORDER BY r.acquiredValue DESC
```

Comment: can you post entire query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toInt and toFloat are not yet added in 2.0.1 release. Check at this [link.](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/packaging/standalone/standalone-enterprise/src/main/distribution/text/enterprise/CHANGES.txt){line 28} Its been planned to release with 2.0.2

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen this. The Neo4j team should update the Cypher Refcard then !

Comment: Yes, they should. I believe it was updated early in error, and has now been reverted to the 2.0.1 version. `toFloat` will re-appear once 2.0.2 is released.  You can see the 2.1 version here: http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.1/